# how to pass platform device information present in my platform data through device tree

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, device-tree

In normal board file, one of the member of my platform data is platform device, is there any way this can be passed through using device tree in linux kernel? In normal board file, I had struct platform_device as member in my platform data.

Comment: See "Platform devices and device trees" http://lwn.net/Articles/448502/

Comment: Joe, One of the member of platform data is another platform device how can I pass it using device tree ?

Answer (score 0):

Device tree node in device tree file is like `platform_device` structure in old board files.
You can define and declare any property (data) you like in a device node of a device tree file.

Kernel provides open firmware (OF) API with lots of functions like `of_find_property()` or  `of_property_read_string()` for device driver to fetch your data from any device in the tree file.